# Only one simultaneous AJAX request in all my browsers, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on web application project that performs multiple simultaneous AJAX requests to one domain. All worked perfectly until some moment - one day I've noticed that AJAX requests are performed one by one, not together as before. I can't understand what's changed, I didn't change anything in the code of project. Moreover, it works fine (asynchronously) on project's users computers, but not on my own. Different browsers on my computer give the same result, one AJAX request at time, all others wait until it completed. I think may be I changed something in network settings of my computer. But I have no idea where to start searching for the problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: maybe you have made some changes in your js code?

Comment: You can go to a site like browserstack.com and check if it downloads one at a time there too. Does it download one file at a time in other websites too for you?

Comment: Thanks guys, I've found the problem. Really it was at the server side. I've added the session handling to the auth process some time ago, and first request blocked the session file, while all others wait for unblock. Problem was solved by closing session right after auth is successful.